# Different anomalies found in each run - Isolation forest

Tags: python, anomaly-detection

I have built an Isolation forest using sklearn and Python, and every time I run the model to find anomalies, I get slightly different results.

My data has 100 rows, and each time I get a different combination of 4-8 anomalies within the 90th-100th row, does anyone know why this could be?

Thank you for your help. 
I have attached some of the code I have used.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
model = IsolationForest(n_estimators = 100, max_samples = 'auto', 
contamination = 'auto')
model.fit(df[['label']])
anomaly = df.loc[df['anomaly']==-1]
```

Comment: Hi, there isn't enough information for us to go by and give advise. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Did you set the parameter random_state?

Comment: @DerekO Yes, i set the random state to 0.

Comment: @achow Yes, I will add some of the code I have used!

Comment: Use `decision_function()` to get a numerical value for the anomaly score. Then check how stable your anomalies scores are across runs. Could be they are just very close to the threshold.

Comment: @jonnor Ok, thank you!